# How to bind SQLite data to textview in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm looking for the simplest way to bind a value in a SQLite column to a textview. I have about a hundred textviews across a number of activities.

I have a DBHelper class to define the table and columns and a SQLController class to define my methods to insert, get and update data. All of this is pretty much boilerplate code.

For each activity I open the database, set my cursor and get the data, then update it back to the database when the activity closes.

Is there a library I can use to bind the fields in my db to the textview directly? I currently use butterknife to bind the data objects to the views and am considering implementing android data binding, but I was wondering if there's a way to go directly from the database to the view without having to write all this boilerplate code?

Comment: assign `android:tag` for each `EditText` you want to be mapped to your db, get all the `EditText`s, iterate over them and load/store the data from/to your db using the tag

Comment: @pskink, that's more or less what I'm doing at the moment, but I was looking for something that makes the job less manual. Kind of like I can do with butterknife where I can do: @ bind (resource) TextView variable and get rid of all the boilerplate.

Comment: what you mean "manual"? manual is writing "@bind" for each TextView (lets say you have 100 EditTexts so you have to manually write 100 "@bind" statements). what i mean is a loop with ~10 lines of code so no matter how many EditTexts you have you dont need to do anything when adding a new EditText